# How to use script to get searched value in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to make search button:

```
<input type="text" name="searchme"  id="searchme" onkeydown="searchme()"  />
<input type="button" value="SearchMe" />
```

I want to get all data from table if textbox is empty else myFunction() will be execute and search.

```
    <script>

 function searchme() {
        var searchvalue;
        searchvalue = document.getElementById('search_id').value;
       alert(searchvalue);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_projectList.php",
            data: {searchvalue: value }
        })
    }

</script>
```

is there any problem with script? What should I add?

Comment: what would you add? just add the part wherein you retrieve the server's response, then translate that data into HTML markup

Comment: above is not working

Comment: Just wondering if you're using jQuery, why still use `document.getElementById` and not `$('#selector')` ?

Comment: ok, but My script should work, bt it is not working even alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looks fine to me. You just need to add `success` for fetching results.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="searchme"  id="searchme" onkeyup="searchme()"  />
```

Change `onkeydown` to `onkeyup`. because on key the you are not able to get the value.

include `jQuery` in `<head>` of your html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

now JS

```
function searchme() {
    var searchvalue;
    searchvalue = $('#searchme').val();
    alert(searchvalue);
    var table = "table_name";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_projectList.php",
        data: {searchvalue: searchvalue, revanue: table},
        success: function (result)
        {
            $(".resultDiv").html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

Where `.resultDiv` is the div where you want to show the result. and remove `'` from `searchvalue` and `revanue`.

[image]

Comment: check your browser console.

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha: Glad to know. You can mark correct this answer so it can be useful to others in future.

Comment: in get_projectList.php `var_dump($_GET);` is not displayed. It display only `array(0) { }`

Comment: check the url in console

Comment: yes, it is because ` data: {searchvalue: searchvalue, revanue: table},` you have to pass the values of `searchvalue` and `revanue`. check my js. I passed static value of `revanue`.

Comment: i use `data: {searchvalue: value }` where var `searchvalue = document.getElementById('search_id').value;`

Comment: check your `js`. you haven't define `value` anywhere. So either define it or change the name to `searchvalue`

Comment: I update script again. Will u plz see it. alert is fine. after removing alert no value is display in .php

Comment: do one thing change `var searchvalue;
        searchvalue = document.getElementById('search_id').value;` with  `var value; value = document.getElementById('search_id').value;`

Comment: It works !!!!! Dnt knw why GET donot works with searchvalue but bt value work now.... nyway thnk u very much

Comment: actually you are not passing `searchvalue` in data while you you are getting value in `var  searchvalue` .

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.  Since you're using jquery.  Might as well use it everywhere.

```
 <input type="text" name="searchme"  id="searchme"  />
```

Then your JS

```
  $('#searchme').keyup(function(){
     var search = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "get_projectList.php",
       data: {searchvalue: search},
       success: function (data)
       {
          $(".results").html(data);
       }
      })
  });
```

But also...you probably dont want your script firing on every keystroke. Instead you should wait a fraction of a second between strokes, to only fire the request when the user is actually done typing.
So like this...

```
// The delay function
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
})();

$('#searchme').keyup(function() {
   var search = $(this).val();
   delay(function(){
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "get_projectList.php",
       data: {searchvalue: search},
       success: function (data)
       {
          $(".results").html(data);
       }
      })
   }, 800 );
});
```

[EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/sfhncjdw/)